# What is lazy initialize in context with Spring Framework or Hibernate and why my code is giving me a "failed to lazy initialize error"?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here is the Code of different classes and interfaces i am using:

**TextData.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="text_data", schema="text_analysis")
@Getter @Setter @ToString @NoArgsConstructor
public class TextData {

    @Id
    @Column(name="text_hash")
    private String textHash;
    @Column(name="summary")
    private String summary;
    @Column(name="summary_length")
    private int summaryLength;
    @Column(name="text_length")
    private int textLength;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="textData")
    private List<KeywordData> keywordData;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="textData")
    private List<ProjectData> projectData;

    public TextData(String textHash, String summary, int summaryLength, int textLength) {
        this.textHash = textHash;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.textLength = textLength;
        this.summaryLength = summaryLength;
    }

}
```

**ProjectData.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project_data", schema="text_analysis")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class ProjectData {

    @Id
    @Column(name="project_id")
    private int projectId;
    @Column(name="project_name")
    private String projectName;
    @Column(name="image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(schema="text_analysis",name="project_text_joiner", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="text_hash"))
    private List<TextData> textData;



    public ProjectData(int projectId, String projectName, String imageUrl) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public ProjectData(int projectId, String projectName) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }
}
```

**KeywordData.java**

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="keyword_data",schema="text_analysis")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class KeywordData {

    @Id
    @Column(name="keyword_id")
    private int keywordId;
    @Column(name="keyword_name")
    private String keywordName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="meaningId")
    private List<MeaningData> meaningData;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(schema="text_analysis",name="keyword_text_joiner", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="keyword_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="text_hash"))
    private List<TextData> textData;


    public KeywordData(int keywordId, String keywordName) {
        this.keywordId = keywordId;
        this.keywordName = keywordName;
    }
}
```

**MeaningData.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="meaning_data", schema="text_analysis")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class MeaningData {

    @Id
    @Column(name="meaning_id")
    private int meaningId;

    @Column(name="meaning_description")
    private String meaningDescription;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="keyword_id",referencedColumnName="keyword_id")
    private KeywordData keywordData;



    public MeaningData(int meaningId, String meaningDescription) {
        this.meaningId = meaningId;
        this.meaningDescription = meaningDescription;
    }
}
```

**Spring Boot main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RecordedApplication {

    public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RecordedApplication.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RecordedApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(TextDataRepository textDataRepository,MeaningDataRepository meaningDataRepository,KeywordDataRepository keywordDataRepository,ProjectDataRepository projectDataRepository) {
        return(args) ->{

            TextData textData = new TextData("12UH","Helium and hydrogen are gases",5,10);
            KeywordData keywordData = new KeywordData(209,"Helium");
            KeywordData keywordData1 = new KeywordData(210,"Hydrogen");
            MeaningData meaningData = new MeaningData(301,"A gas");
            MeaningData meaningData1 = new MeaningData(302,"A Laughing gas");
            MeaningData meaningData2 = new MeaningData(303,"A gas");
            ProjectData projectData = new ProjectData(101,"Gases");

            projectDataRepository.save(projectData);
            textDataRepository.save(textData);
            textDataRepository.save(textData);
            keywordDataRepository.save(keywordData);
            keywordDataRepository.save(keywordData1);
            meaningDataRepository.save(meaningData);
            meaningDataRepository.save(meaningData1);
            meaningDataRepository.save(meaningData2);



            log.info("-------------Objects in db---------");
            for(ProjectData tempProjectData : projectDataRepository.findAll()) {
                log.info(tempProjectData.toString() + "");

            }
            log.info("-------------Objects in db---------");
            for(TextData tempTextData : textDataRepository.findAll()) {
                log.info(tempTextData.toString() + "");

            }
            log.info("-------------Objects in db---------");
            for(KeywordData tempKeywordData : keywordDataRepository.findAll()) {
                log.info(tempKeywordData.toString() + "");

            }
            log.info("-------------Objects in db---------");
            for(MeaningData tempMeaningData : meaningDataRepository.findAll()) {
                log.info(tempMeaningData.toString() + "");

            }
        };
    }

}
```

Repositories for all the entities above are empty repositories extending  *JpaRepositories*.
It will be of great help if along with the solution you can provide a good explanation for the same and guide me to proper resources as I am quite new to the Spring and Hibernate Platforms.

**Error which i am getting**

```
: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.TextAnalysis.Entities.ProjectData.textData, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:606) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:621) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't demonstrate the tiniest effort of researching the problem. There are tons of references on and off Stack Overflow that answer this question, easy to find by just plopping the exception in a search engine.

Comment: I see your point as I was going through a book related to Hibernate and JPA I figured out the exact problem under the hood. It would have been nice though to give someone a little direction when you see them not going anywhere because its something new to me and I didn't know where exactly go for references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because hibernate requires a Session for lazy loading of data, i.e. fetching those one to many and many to many relationships data as they are also the part of  the entity you are querying. Don't worry about the data, it might have loaded in the database, check for yourself.

It's better that one goes through the book **Java Persistence with Hibernate** it will work as a great reference as one is bound to get stuck understanding the Persistence API.